# Where and from whom can I learn more about individualist anarchism?

Tags: reference-request, anarchism

I'd like to learn about individualist anarchism.
Do you know a free online resource for this?
Who are contemporary philosophers working on this subject?
Is there an online forum for individualists?

Comment: What have you found out so far? Generally speaking, the more information you give, the more likely it gets that someone will take the time to answer your question.

Comment: I just searched the phrase in google and read some of the results. I am looking for some experts' advise for further study.

Answer (score 3):

As a person, who studied anarchism a bit, i can assure you there's nothing wrong to start from Wikipedia page on [individualist anarchism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Individualist_anarchism).

The early individual anarchists were [Max Stirner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Stirner) and [Benjamin Tucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin_R._Tucker). I recommend Stirner's *[The Ego and Its Own](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ego_and_Its_Own)*, it's an easy read and proved way more interesting than Nietzsche or Ayn Rand. [Proudhon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre-Joseph_Proudhon) is also a major inspiration for individualist anarchism for his accounts on market economy.

For the full view you may also look at Marx's critique of Stirner in *[The German Ideology](http://www.marxists.org/archive/marx/works/1845/german-ideology/index.htm)* (part III: Saint Max) and communist anarchists' view on individualist anarchism on [An Anarchist FAQ](http://anarchism.pageabode.com/afaq/secGcon.html).

Today individualist anarchists arguably developed into 3 currents: Neo-mutualism (advocated by the likes of [Kevin Carson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Carson)), [agorism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agorism) and so-called [anarcho-capitalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarcho-capitalism). Communist anarchists [reject](http://anarchism.pageabode.com/afaq/SecFcon.html) the last branch, and Konkin also [critiqued](http://www.anthonyflood.com/konkinreplytorothbard.htm) Rothbard.

Sites, where individualist anarchists hang out include [Alliance of the Libertarian Left](http://praxeology.net/all-left.htm) and [Center for a Stateless Society](http://c4ss.org/). Check out also Reddit sections [Agorism](http://www.reddit.com/r/Agorism) and [MarketAnarchism](http://www.reddit.com/r/MarketAnarchism).